# why is the response from ajax request is being displayed in error msg div when it should relocate the page to logged-in.php

Tags: php, jquery

There is something weird happening. When there are no errors in the php action page and after it validates the user input it echoes success and the data gets inserted into the table. In jquery it should change the page location if the data received is "success" but instead it is displaying the "success" in the div responsible for displaying errors like wrong password combination or username/email already exist.

I used the same way with the login function to validate data and when the response is login_success it does relocate the page to logged-in.php however it is not working with this signup form.

The errors are being displayed fine but the only problem is with relocating the page on success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the Jquery code:

```
$("body").delegate("#signup-btn", "click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "signup.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: $("#signup-form").serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "success"){
                window.location.href="logged-in.php";
            }
            else{
                $("#signup_error_msg").html(data);
                $("#signup_error_msg").css("display", "block");
            }
        }
    })
})
```

signup.php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password1']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$psw1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password1']);
$psw2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password2']);
$fName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fName']);
$lName = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['lName']);
$addr = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['address']);
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['mobile']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);

if(empty($username) || empty($email)|| empty($fName) || empty($lName) || empty($addr) || empty($mobile) ||
empty($psw1)){
    echo "Fill the form below.";
    exit();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' OR email = '$email'";
$run_sql = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($run_sql) > 0){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_sql);

        if($row['username'] == $username){
        echo "username already exists. Try another one.";
        }

        if($psw1 != $psw2){
            echo "Passwords do not match.";
        }

        if($row['email'] == $email){
            echo "Email already exists. Try another one.";
        }
    }
    else{
            $psw = md5($psw1);
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, first_name, last_name, address, mobile, email) VALUES ('$username', '$psw',
            '$fName', '$lName', '$addr', '$mobile', '$email')";
            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['fName'] = $fName;
            $_SESSION['lName'] = $lName;
            echo "success";
        }

}
```

Comment: You might be having whitespace issue . So , use `$.trim(data)` this will remove any whitespaces then compare it with other string . Also, try using json to send response back to ajax.